# Slow loading Magento Commerce homepage

Tags: website

I have recently changed by website and it is really loading slowly :- dancemidisamples.com

here is a report http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120906_78_ANK/

As far as I can tell the is a issue with this section of code

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.dancemidisamples.com/skin/frontend/base/default /favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.dancemidisamples.com/skin/frontend/base/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var urlSkinsite='http://www.dancemidisamples.com/skin/frontend/em0040/default/';
//]]>
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var BLANK_URL = 'http://www.dancemidisamples.com/js/blank.html';
var BLANK_IMG = 'http://www.dancemidisamples.com/js/spacer.gif';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Does anyone have any ideas, people have told me it my DNS but it has a 49ms response rate according to http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120906_78_ANK/1/details/cached/

We are hosted with rackspace so I dont see how it could be the server. Its a dedicated server not cloud hosted

Comment: Careful--the report you've provided says roughly 7 seconds are spent waiting for the first byte.

Comment: You also really need to learn about limiting the number of http requests. Look into Google Closure compiler or something similar.

Comment: Your bigest performance hit is 7 seconds you spend on the server preparing the first page not the JavaScript

Comment: I can't really troubleshoot that, but I had this great [blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/performance-is-a-feature.html) bookmarked that might be relevant to your interests.

Comment: Here are some of the solutions:

http://serverfault.com/questions/326164/how-to-optimize-time-to-first-byte-ttfb

http://serverfault.com/questions/350062/the-strange-case-of-mr-time-to-first-byte

Comment: Like @TheBlackBenzKid said the script is doing nothing and the load report that you post shows that there is a really long wait between the initial request and the first byte sent by the server. I think that you might look into your server configuration... What about hardware?
Which web server are you using?

Comment: Log into your server and look at memory usage. Also look for swapping, which can kill performance in a major way. If this is true, increasing the memory on the system can be a huge help. See this for some other info: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/168/optimising_your_web_stack_performance_for_magento

Comment: Have you open_basedir enabled ? If yes disable it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with your **webserver** rather than your code, looking at the report you linked http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120906_78_ANK/

Your browser had to wait **6.302s** before starting to load the page, you should be investigating the **Start Render** column as that is what is causing the majority of your slowdown.

This is probably because you have poor DNS resolution and a low powered (shared) server that cannot process the request particularly quickly.

You should also look at consolodating files and including your CSS all at once etc, your website loaded **76** files at a total of **1,139 KB**

Though that doesn't explain the 6 seconds of loading before the page started, it does explain the **7s** (13-6) wait while the browser loaded and rendered the content

**Suggestions:**

- Look at getting a **new web server** (or increasing the power - ram/cpu), perhaps a VPS if you are using a shared host
- Enable **page caching**  (System -> Cache Management)
- Research how to **reduce** the number of **HTTP requests** your website makes
- Investigate your **DNS resolution** (using one of the many tools available online)

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid The comments on this answer were deleted by a moderator (ME, actually) because they were inflammatory, argumentative, and a razor's edge away from [Stack Exchange etiquette violations](http://serverfault.com/faq#etiquette). If you have an issue with this answer which you would like to raise in a comment you may do so, however please bear in mind our network-wide policy on civility.  Argumentative and non-constructive comments don't last long when I'm on the site - they get edited to be appropriate, or blasted into the void.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your using Magento Commerce on a poor performing server. Magento is a highly tuned eCommerce script (terrible IMO for this and several reasons). I also see your on Rackspace; this is even more concerning. You need to post information about your setup, the whois records look corrupted too. It could also be caching and many other reasons.

This script:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.dancemidisamples.com/skin/frontend/base/default /favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.dancemidisamples.com/skin/frontend/base/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var urlSkinsite='http://www.dancemidisamples.com/skin/frontend/em0040/default/';
//]]>
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var BLANK_URL = 'http://www.dancemidisamples.com/js/blank.html';
var BLANK_IMG = 'http://www.dancemidisamples.com/js/spacer.gif';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Is doing nothing to effect the site speed.

## Speed up Magento

[Why is Magento so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639213/why-is-magento-so-slow)

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the site using Chrome's built-in Developer Tools (CTRL + SHIFT + I). The PageSpeed function lists numerous improvements that will speed your site up, but we are talking about milliseconds here.

Using the Network function (still in Developer Tools), we can see that all the many images, js  & css files take small amounts of time, but even combined, they are dwarf by the initial time to return the page, which takes over 5 secs from my PC.

Digging down further, if I click on the html item, and go to the Timing tab, I can see that it takes 14ms to connect, 5s 'waiting' and 164ms to receive the code. Which suggests the problem lies with either your hosts nameservers or your web server.

[image]

I don't think it is DNS related as such; we all talk to different DNS server yet experience the same wait. Unless your TTL is very low (not - it appears to be @ 24hrs), forcing everybody to go back to your registrars nameservers, it suggest the nameservers at your host may be at fault. If not, then the problem probably lies with your web server.

I'm afraid I don't have the time (and probably the skills) to take you any further at this time - hope this helps.

Comment: Nice answer. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I'll propose an answer that doesnt mean going in and rewriting all the dang SQL statements.

It's actually really easy:

1. delete the line that adds the new items list to your homepage
2. add these lines in its place

   New Items
   {{block type="catalog/product_widget_new" products_count="5" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml"}}</div>
3. got to app/design/frontend/default/hellovieo/template/catalog/product/widget/new/content/
4. edit new.phtml
5. find and delete the following lines

   div class="widget-title">
       h2>< ?php echo $this->__('New Products') ?>

Once you save this, you are done. My load times went from 10 seconds to less than 1 second.